# docker cannot start container: "permission denied"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Upon starting a docker container, I get the following error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:175: exec user process caused "permission denied"
```

`sudo` does not fix it. I have all permissions.
`docker-compose` only shows the container crashing in the same way.

I use Linux and the `Dockerfile` is on a cifs-share. Starting from a locally mounted drive, everything works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted at [here](https://github.com/docker-library/hello-world/issues/19#issuecomment-393300634) the filesystem is no-exec. I.e. executing scripts or binaries from there is not allowed. You can test that by finding e.g. a shellscript, checking it has the execute bit set with `ls -l` and then try to run it. Furthermore, looking at the mount-parameters can reveal the problem:

```
//nas.local/home on /cifs/h type cifs ( <lots of options omitted> , noexec)
```

Interestingly, the command that mounted the share did not explicitly request `noexec`. However the mount came out this way anyway. Adding `-o exec` to the mounting command and remounting fixed it.

Comment: do we need to add this in dockerfle? If not, can you please tell me where to put this? I am new to Docker, so might not understand the technical stuff.

Comment: Your problem is not with Docker, It is with the filesystem. If you create the CIFS-mount manually on the CLI, you add the `-o exec` in there. If it "just shows up" after booting, then you will find a line that creates your mount in the file `/etc/fstab`. Add `exec` to the options there. I hope that helps, because I have no idea how to describe it better. I looked at a few websites and this seems to explain it quite well: https://www.putorius.net/mount-windows-share-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by changing the top line in train file.

It was

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

I changed it to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5
```

depending on what version of python i had installed.

Comment: What is a Train file?

Comment: train file can be any file which you are trying to run. when you do docker run xyz train, train is the file you are trying to run.